# Does $^{\frac12}x=e^{W(\ln x)}$, or not?

Tags: real-analysis, tetration, lambert-w

Whenever I see tetration discussed here, I inevitably see it asserted that there's no consistent continuous definition for tetration. However, it seems to me that

1. If we restrict ourselves to positive real values, $^{\frac12}x=e^{W(\ln x)}$ is the only consistent definition for $^{\frac12}x$; and
2. This definition is sufficient to define tetration to any real height, if we further say that $\displaystyle^tx = {\lim_{a \to t}}\; ^ax$. So, what gives? I don't especially think I'm smarter than professional mathematicians, so if there's an inconsistency I'd like to be able to recognize it. Is there?

Comment: Could you expand on how you would define ${}^tx$ using only integer values and the fact that $^{\frac12}x=e^{W(\ln x)}$?

Comment: so $e^{W(W(\ln(x)))}=e^x $ ?   Try W|A http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e^[W[W[ln[x]]]]

Comment: How are we supposed to know this given we can't really evaluate $^{1/2}x$ well?